# Best practice for Redux actions based on current store

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to work out - unsuccessfully - what the recommendations are for dispatching an action based on the current state in the Redux store.

I have a setup where, upon logging in, the ID of the current user is stored under `auth.currentUser`.

I also have separately the details of users stored under `users[id]`.

Firstly, I'd like my `loadUser(id)` action creator to not bother making API calls if the user details are already available. Secondly, I'd like to have a `loadCurrentUser()` action creator that makes the call to get the user based on that stored Current User ID.

What is the best way of doing this? I know I can do it relatively easily using redux thunk, but is that best or are there better ways? So far I've avoided using that - using redux promise middleware for my asynchronous actions instead.

Edit: To clarify what I want to do.

When my component loads, it will need to ensure that the current user details are loaded. It would do this by wiring in `loadCurrentUser()` to be dispatched.

Firstly, this action needs to load the user based on the ID stored elsewhere in the store. Secondly, it needs to only do that if this user with that ID isn't already in the store.

Comment: if am not mistaken action creator are used to store data in the store, not to get data from store.

Comment: Are you asking how to make async calls?  This question isn't very clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Dedicate a portion of your store to holding user data and connect that to whatever component is relevant. From there, you can make dispatch calls based on the status of your user. Lifecycle methods are a common place to put logic like this.

```
componentWillMount() {
  if (this.props.user.id){ //assuming id is undefined if no user
    this.props.dispatchAction()
  }
}
```

Comment: So, to ensure I understand that right:
* Wire the current user ID in to the component
* Wire the user details based on that current user ID into the component
* Wire in a dispatcher to load a user by ID
* Perform the logic for which ID to use and whether to load the user or not in the component instead.

I can see that working, but it feels like that logic belongs in the Redux actions and not in the UI components, surely?

Comment: @Graham If you do it in the Redux actions you lose the power and flexibility you have with React lifecycles. Controlling when you dispatch your actions is a very straightforward process when you use lifecycles. Ultimately, there are many implementations to solve your general problem. This is just mine.